# Option Tree integration of Custom CSS

Tags: functions, theme-options

I would love to integrate Custom CSS field from my Option Tree plugin to the code, but if I try to integrate them following way into `functions.php`, it ends up with *Fatal error: Call to undefined function ot_get_option() in /data/web/virtuals/51889/virtual/www/domains/demo.kybernaut.cz/ommo-wp/wp-content/themes/ommo/functions.php on line 36* So it looks like that I call the function before loading `ot_get_option` function from Option tree, is that possible? What to do with it? Thanks a lot!

```
//Custom CSS
    if (ot_get_option('css', false) != false) {
        function css() {
            return '<style>'.ot_get_option('css').'</style>';   
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'css', 100 );
    }
```

Comment: What is Option Tree? How is definition of that function loaded and at which point during load?

Comment: Its a plugin from repo [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) for creating the Theme Options.

Comment: `css` is an incredibly generic function name, it's going to cause issues for you further down the line, consider adding a prefix or namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

never* execute code outside of hooks as you are more likely to call a function or use a variable before they were declared and initialized.

your code should be

```
function css() {
    if (ot_get_option('css', false) != false) {
            echo'<style>'.ot_get_option('css').'</style>';   
        }
    }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'css', 100 );
```

*never say never, but this is a rule to follow unless you have a very explicit reason to ignore it.